# Jest cant find module with ".svg?react" Vite + React + Ts + Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, vite

I am trying to test my app made with vite + react + ts but when I want to make my dashboard component, jest complains that it cannot find the "svg?react" module.

This is the problem with jest when the i start the test

```
Cannot find module './brand.svg?react' from 'src/sections/dashboard/Dashboard.tsx'
```

This is my vite.config.ts

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'

dotenv.config();
export default defineConfig((configEnv) => {
    const isDevelopment = configEnv.mode === "development";

    return {
        plugins: [react(), svgr()],
        css: {
            modules: {
                generateScopedName: isDevelopment ? "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]" : "[hash:base64:5]",
            },
        },
        define: {
            "process.env": process.env,
        },
    };
});
```

This is my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/tests/setupTests.ts"],
    testMatch: ["<rootDir>/tests/**/*.(test).(ts|tsx)"],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/tests/e2e/"],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": [
            "@swc/jest",
            {
                sourceMaps: true,
                jsc: {
                    parser: {
                        syntax: "typescript",
                        tsx: true,
                    },
                    transform: {
                        react: {
                            runtime: "automatic",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(svg$|svg?react)": "<rootDir>/tests/svg.mock.js",
        "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
            "jest-transform-stub",
    },
};
```

This is my svg.mock.js

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-anonymous-default-export */
export default "SvgrURL";
export const ReactComponent = "div";
```

Previously, I looked for how to solve the vite problem with svg with vite-plugin-svgr and it worked but now this generates conflicts with Jest. I'm really stuck with this but with CRA this doesn't happen.